# How to change ZSTD compression level for files written via Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, compression, parquet, zstd

It is stated that the default zstd compression level is 1 in Spark documentation. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html

I set this property to different values both in *spark-defaults.conf*,

and inside the code like

```
val conf = new SparkConf(false)
conf.set("spark.io.compression.zstd.level", "22")
val spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf).getOrCreate()
..
```

Reading same input and saving/writing it in parquet format with zstd compression multiple times did not change the output file size at all. How can one adjust this compression level in Spark?

Comment: zstd compression level 22 is in the --ultra territory. Just "go to eleven" and check if this works for you.

Comment: What you pointed out is true for the command line zstd tool. However, it matters not which value you set within Spark since it uses an open source zstd JNI implementation and those things are handled probably in https://github.com/luben/zstd-jni/blob/5ae1cf6b3cee822b78cc2a052dcf0a294b2946db/src/main/native/jni_zstd.c

Comment: The thing is level parameter of setLevel function here ,https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/0494dc90af48ce7da0625485a4dc6917a244d580/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/io/CompressionCodec.scala
which is read from SparkConf as conf.get(IO_COMPRESSION_ZSTD_LEVEL) does not seem to take effect somehow. I tested it with different values including ones that are below ultra territory.

Comment: Just curious, did someone try to launch a fairly large spark pipeline (at least with some joins) using `spark.io.compression.codec="zstd"` and `spark.io.compression.zstd.level` set to more than `20`? :)

Comment: Hi @ei-grad I tried and asked my question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77204328/how-to-set-zstd-compression-level-in-aws-glue-job, so far still no luck.

Answer (score 3):

The parameter `spark.io.compression.zstd.level` is about the codec used to compress an intermediate files - serialized RDDs, shuffle, broadcast, checkpoints. In most cases the only important thing there is the compression speed, so default `1` would be the best choice (one also should set `spark.io.compression.codec` to `zstd`, for this parameter to have effect).

Sadly, there is no ability to specify a compression level for Parquet codec specified by `spark.sql.parquet.compression.codec` in Spark.

Starting from Spark 3.2 (with `parquet-mr>=1.12.0`), there is `parquet.compression.codec.zstd.level` option, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
In [5]: for i in [1, 5, 10]: df.write.option('parquet.compression.codec.zstd.level', i
   ...: ).parquet(f"test-{i}.parquet", compression='zstd', mode='overwrite')
                                                                                
In [6]: !du -sh test-*.parquet
40M test-10.parquet
40M test-1.parquet
40M test-5.parquet
```

As a workaround, one could use the Parquet implementation from the `arrow` project (directly in C++, or via pyarrow / go / etc; it allows to specify `compression_level` for each column's codec, as well as default `compression_level` value) to repack the data before writing it into the warehouse.

Sadly, the `arrow-rs` Parquet implementation [doesn't allow](https://github.com/apache/arrow-rs/blob/344c552/parquet/src/compression.rs#L318-L319) to specify the `compression_level` too. But luckily, `parquet2` wich is used in `arrow2` (transmute-free rust implementation of arrow) - [does](https://github.com/jorgecarleitao/parquet2/pull/128).

Answer (score 1):

you can use something like:

```
df.write
 .option("parquet.compression.codec.zstd.level", "22")
 .parquet("/your/output/dir")
```

more details in this jira: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-39743

Comment: It seems that `parquet.compression.codec.zstd.level` is not used in flow of how parquet zstd compressor is initialized in Spark. Mentioned issue has been marked to resolved by PR, which clarifies `spark.io.compression.zstd.level` in docs :-(.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the level by configuring parquet.compression.codec.zstd.level eg ...config("parquet.compression.codec.zstd.level","3")

For more properties take a look in org.apache.parquet.hadoop.codec.ZstandardCodec.java

As the other mentioned 22 seems a little bit extreme. I would be curious what's your use case.