# How to set "zstd" compression level in AWS Glue job?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, aws-glue, delta-lake, zstd

#### Background

"zstd" compression codec has 22 compression levels. I read [this Uber blog](https://www.uber.com/blog/cost-efficiency-big-data/). Regarding compressing time and file size, I verified using `df.to_parquet` with our data and got same experiment result. So I am hoping to set compression level to 19 in our AWS Glue Spark job which also writes the data to Delta Lake.

#### Experiment 1

My AWS Glue job is using "Glue 4.0 - Spark 3.3, Scala 2, Python 3" version.

Here is my code

```py
import sys
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job

args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ["JOB_NAME"])
sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args["JOB_NAME"], args)

S3bucket_node1 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    format_options={},
    connection_type="s3",
    format="parquet",
    connection_options={
        "paths": [
            "s3://my-bucket/data/raw-parquet/motor/"
        ],
        "recurse": True,
    },
    transformation_ctx="S3bucket_node1",
)

additional_options = {
    "path": "s3://my-bucket/data/delta-tables/motor/",
    "mergeSchema": "true",
}
sink_to_delta_lake_node3_df = S3bucket_node1.toDF()
sink_to_delta_lake_node3_df.write.format("delta").options(**additional_options).mode(
    "overwrite"
).save()

job.commit()
```

Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/74276832/2000548, I may use `--conf parquet.compression.codec.zstd.level=19`. (Note the author who wrote the answer said it does not seem working. On the other side, Uber in the blog made it work, so I am thinking there could be a way to set "zstd" compression level correctly in Spark)

Here is my `--conf`:

```bash
--conf spark.sql.parquet.compression.codec=zstd
--conf parquet.compression.codec.zstd.level=19
```

I added these config in my Glue job by "Job details -> Advanced properties -> Job parameters":

- Key: `--conf`
- Value: `spark.sql.parquet.compression.codec=zstd --conf parquet.compression.codec.zstd.level=19`

(This is the [current way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59261013/2000548) to set multiple `--conf` in AWS Glue job which I have verified working as expected before)

I compared with compression level 3. However, both compression level 19 and 3 generated exact same parquet file size 97 MB (97,002,126 bytes) in the Delta table.

To make sure different "zstd" compression level on this data have different size, I tried Python code:

```py
df.to_parquet(
  local_parquet_path,
  engine="pyarrow",
  compression="zstd",
  compression_level=19
)
```

The file size using compression level 19 is 92% of the file size using compression level 3, which means for this data, when the compression level very different, there is difference for the file size. So I feel `--conf parquet.compression.codec.zstd.level=19` in Spark does not function as expected.

How to set "zstd" compression level in AWS Glue job? Thanks!

---

#### Experiment 2 ~ 4 (9/29/2023)

Tried these combinations:

```bash
--conf spark.sql.parquet.compression.codec=zstd
--conf parquet.compression.codec.zstd.level=19
```

```bash
--conf spark.sql.parquet.compression.codec=zstd
--conf spark.io.compression.codec=zstd
--conf spark.io.compression.zstd.level=19
```

```bash
--conf spark.sql.parquet.compression.codec=zstd
--conf parquet.compression.codec.zstd.level=19
--conf spark.io.compression.codec=zstd
--conf spark.io.compression.zstd.level=19
```

Still got exact same "zstd" parquet file size in the Delta Lake compared to without setting any compression level or setting to 3.

---

#### Experiment 5 (9/29/2023)

If only use

```bash
--conf spark.io.compression.codec=zstd
--conf spark.io.compression.zstd.level=19
```

This actually make the final file to Snappy format like `part-00000-1c8c7408-b14f-4ba1-9030-ecc437a2f8d3-c000.snappy.parquet`. It means `spark.io.compression.codec=zstd` does not work as expected.

Comment: Can you try `spark.io.compression.zstd.level`?

Comment: Thanks @ErmiyaEskandary just tired `spark.io.compression.zstd.level=19`, unfortunately, still same size.

Answer (score 0):

The `spark.io.compression.codec` isn't used for writing the resulting parquet files - it's used for writing compressed internal data such as RDD partitions, event logs, broadcast variables and shuffle outputs  (check [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#compression-and-serialization)).

From the discussion in the linked Jira, it looks like this is not configurable in Spark (but maybe I need to check the source code for it).

Comment: Appreciate, Alex!